# Update table using Linq and Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

When I try to update table using following code I get error message

"Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint"

How Can I create a new instance and update data in database.

```
   IEnumerable<BookData> bookData = GetBookData(...);

   BookDataContext bookDB = new BookDataContext ();

   bookDB.UpdateTable<MCDB.BookTable>(bookDB.BookTable,bookData);



class BookTable
{
    public string bookName { get; set; }
    public string  authorName { get; set; }
}
```

#### Extension Method

```
 public static void UpdateTable<T>(this DataContext context, Table<T> tbl, IEnumerable<BookData> data)
    where T : class
    {
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            context.GetTable<T>().InsertOnSubmit(new T());
            // Error in above statement 

             // I want to do something like this
             context.GetTable<T>().InsertOnSubmit(new T
                {
                    bName = item.bookName
                    aName = item.authorName,
                });
         }
         context.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

PS:  I know the another way but I want to update table using extension method

```
using ( BookDataContext bookDB = new BookDataContext ())
{
  //code 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding a [new constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28VS.80%29.aspx)?

```
where T : class, new()
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the [constraint `where T : new()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx):

```
public static void UpdateTable<T>(
    this DataContext context, Table<T> tbl,
    IEnumerable<BookData> data
) where T : class, new() {
    // details
}
```

Note that `T` can not be abstract, and the `new` constraint must be the last constraint listed.

Whoa, just noticed this:

```
context.GetTable<T>().InsertOnSubmit(new T
    {
        bName = item.bookName
        aName = item.authorName,
    }
);
```

You can not get away this unless you add a constraint to `T` so that the compiler knows that `T` has properties named `bName` and `aName`. At a minimum you need to specify

```
where T : BookData, new()
```

where `BookData` is a class that has those properties defined. This will specify that `T` is  `BookData` or derives from `BookData` and that it has a public parameterless constructor. In this case you can do away with the constraint `where T : class`. Alternatively you can specify

```
where T : IBookData, new()
```

where `IBookData` is an interface defining the two properties that you are using. This constraint specifies that `T` is a type that implements `IBookData` and that it has a public parameterless constructor.

Given that, I don't understand why you are doing this generically.

Comment: Hi Jason

  
 I thought may be I use extension to method to solve my question which I ask before(still waiting for answer)
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045601/update-table-using-linq-to-sql